# svn log on copied file gives Unable to find repository location

Tags: svn, copy, repository

I've got a set of files which I'm copying and renameing within an SVN repository in order to try to retain as much as possible of the files history. As well as copying from source to target, I already have the new files in their new form and with some updates to their contents in another location. I'm applying changes to the files by copying an updated version of the new file from another location on top of the new file. So the sequence looks like:

```
# Copy and rename the files within svn
svn cp <old-directory><old-file-name> <new-directory>/<new-filename>

# Copy and update version of the new file in place
cp <updated-directory>/<new-filename> <new-directory>/<new-filename>
```

I can then take a look at the status of the files and I get:

```
A  +    <new-directory>/<new-filename>
```

Which I understand to mean *This file will be moved (after commit)*

Incidentally, the reason I'm copying rather than moving is that the code is rather critical and so we want to do the move in phases.

In some cases the `<old-directory>` is the same as the `<new-directory>` so it's just a name change and some internal alterations. Performing a `svn log` on these files gives a normal log history. However in other cases, when copying the files, the `<new-directory>` did not exist and I've had to create a new directory in svn which I did using:

```
svn mkdir <new-directory>
```

these files and the directory also appear as `A +` as follows:

```
A       <new-directory>
A  +    <new-directory>/<new-filename-one>
A  +    <new-directory>/<new-filename-two>
```

Although when I try to do an `svn log` on these files, I get the following error message:

```
svn: Unable to find repository location for '<new-directory>/<new-filename>' in revision 0
```

I'm not sure if I've made an error here: Should I perhaps have committed the `svn mkdir` before adding the files to the directory? Perhaps it will resolve itself after I commit everything? I've not committed the files yet as I don't particularly want to get deeper into a hole that I'll have to unpick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if you make a new directory in Subversion, and add files into that directory, the `svn status` only shows that you're adding a new file **and** that directory.

```
$ svn mkdir foo
A       foo

$ cd foo
$ touch bar fu barfu
$ svn add *
A       bar
A       fu
A       barfu

$ cd ..
$ svn status
A       foo
A       foo\bar
A       foo\fu
A       foo\barfu
```

Note that my status shows that I'm adding the directory `foo` and the three files under that directory.

When I try to copy a file to a non-existent directory, I get the error `svn: E155007: Path '<myNewDir>' is not a directory`, so I have to make that directory first.

So, I guess the question is what does your ***complete***`svn status` look like? Does it include the new directory, or just the files you moved?

Also, is it possible that your directory name begins with `http://` or `foo://` and that's what is confusing Subversion?

Your error message is:

```
svn: Unable to find repository location for '<new-directory>/<new-filename>' in revision 0
```

I noticed the *`revision 0`* on the end, and the fact it's talking about *repository location* which looks like it's trying to access not your local working directory, but a URL.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the `svn status` of the new directory with (new) files. The directory names are fairly normal and don't contain anything unusual such as `http://` etc. I think that the issue here may be that the directory that these copied files reside in is not quite there yet as it hasn't been committed.

Comment: What revision of Subversion are you using? That hasn't been an issue for quite a long time.

Comment: I get `svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011) compiled Jul 12 2011, 12:40:17` so not particularly old I wouldn't have thought given that the latest is 1.6.20.

Comment: In the end, I decided to take the plunge and just commit the changes. Pleased to say I think it has worked. I suspect that the directory being added, but not committed, to the repository was causing this issue.